# TLS 1.3, IIS 10.0 support

Tags: windows, security, ssl, iis

We are running an asp.net application in IIS 10.0 (windows server 2016) and installed SSL certificate. One of our clients was asking us about supporting TLS 1.3. My understanding is that TLS 1.3 is still in draft and I found no reference for server 2016 and TLS 1.3. What can we do to provide support for TLS 1.3 (other than waiting for this version to be officially released)? 
Would it be correct to say that we will support TLS 1.3 when Server 2016 begins to support it?

Comment: You are correct. It is still a [draft](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-tls-tls13-18). Your client's expectation is unreasonable. You should just tell your customer that supporting TLS1.3 is up to Microsoft, not you.

Comment: Thank you. This is helpful.

Comment: *"What can we do to provide support for TLS 1.3..."* - OpenSSL, NSS, GnuTLS, etc. They are are closely following the drafts as they appear (I lurk or the TLS working group list). In the bigger picture, it would probably mean using, say, Nginx or STunnel as a front end or SSL-terminator, and then forwarding requests to an IIS machine behind it. Maybe you could run a TLS 1.3 version of the site based on the latest draft at port 8443 to wow some clients. Let them know its experimental. But like EJP said, its probably better to wait for the draft to be adopted.

Comment: While this does not provide an 'IIS solution' your problem, a workaround would be to use Cloudflare CDN. TLS 1.3 draft is supported at the moment and is relatively easy to setup - also on their free account.

Comment: If you use Cloudflare then you're able to restrict incoming web requests to those using TLS 1.3 only if you want, but that will cover the User --> Cloudflare dataflow only, Cloudflare don't yet support TLS1.3 from their Edge to the origin Server (i.e. your LBs/Web Servers). As per [link]https://caniuse.com/#feat=tls1-3 TLS1.3 is supported from a number of major Browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari) but Edge and IE don't support it yet.  This means IE/Edge requests result in a "Cannot securely connect to this page This might be because the site uses outdated or unsafe TLS security settings.

Answer (score 2):

This is old, but I think it deserves an update at this point. TLS 1.3 has been finalized for over a year now. It's no longer in a draft as of 8/2018 and is finalized and published. Yet still, no support from MS. This is extremely poor on their part. All the ciphers in TLS 1.2 and lower have been compromised or are vulnerable to attack - such as timing-based attacks. Only TLS 1.3 AEAD based ciphers are - as of this time - uncompromised or not known to be vulnerable.

Come on MS. It's been almost 1.5 years. I thought you were serious about security!!! You talk the talk - now walk the walk and get us TLS 1.3 support!!!

Comment: What question does this answer, or is it just a rant against Microsoft?

Comment: The goal being if enough chatter appears online that MS will spring into action. And what's wrong with a rant if the criticism is valid?